# General flow with regard to DMA Engine APIs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, dma

I am using the Zynq ZCU102 SOC. I have a custom AXI IP on the PL and linux running on the PS. I have written the code for a device driver to transfer data between the processor and the IP. Now I want to offload the transfers to a CDMA using the function calls provided by the DMA Engine. I have looked at the documentation for using the DMA Engine APIs and the "axidmatest.c" file but have a few queries.

For a transfer say, from the memory to the device, I understand that the source buffer is mapped using the "dma_map_single" function. How is the destination address on the device passed to the DMA?
In "axidmatest.c" I am not able to find the destination address being set anywhere.
(Similarly how is the source physical address passed to the DMA during a transfer from device to memory?)

In "axidmatest.c" the function "dmaengine_slave_config()" is not at all called? Isn't it necessary to populate the fields of the dma_slave_config structure?

In the structure "dma_chan" returned by "request_dma_chan()", there is a field "struct device * slave" which is described to be a pointer to the device using that channel. Where is this being set?(Since the device pointer being passed to request_dma_chan() is that of the DMA engine)

What is the use case of "dmaengine_desc_attach_metadata()"?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *axidmatest.c* works only against memory-to-memory type of transfers.

Comment: Yes I observed that. But I am not able to figure out where the destination address is being set for a MEM_TO_DEV transfer and the source address for a DEV_TO_MEM transfer.

Comment: If you observed what I said in the first comment, how comes you are talking about other transfer types in the second part of your comment?

Comment: I think I have not fully understood the working. Doesn't memory-to-memory type of transfers require the specification of both source and destination addresses? This is the first time I am encountering the DMA engine. So, I might be asking very basic questions. Thanks